# calling a function with response as JSON data from another jquery and get response back

Tags: jquery, ajax, json.net

I want to pass database query result to jquery in JSON format, for that I am thinking of this
first function will get data from some c# function and then pass that data as input to another jquery for processing on webservice.

I am new to this.. Can somebody help me

first function :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var Result1;
var Result2;

function btnJquery_Click() {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "Default.asmx/GetData", // this will get data from c# function
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function CallanotherFunction (response) { Result1= JSON.parse(response);} 
    }); 

function CallanotherFunction () {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "Default.asmx/GetData", // this will get data from c# function
        data: Result1,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function CallanotherFunction (response) {Result2= JSON.parse(response); } 
    }); 

     }
</script>
```

This is just imaginary code; won't work.. please help me with code

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.done()`

```
function btnJquery_Click() {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "Default.asmx/GetData", // this will get data from c# function
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { 
        Result1= JSON.parse(response);

        }).done(function(Result1){
         CallanotherFunction (Result1)
        }) 
    });
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.asmx/GetData", // this will get data from c# function
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        Result1 = JSON.parse(data); //1st ajax data
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.asmx/GetData", // this will get data from c# function
            data: Result1, //used 1st ajax data
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                Result2 = JSON.parse(response);//here 2nd ajax data based on first ajax call
            }
        });
    }
});
```